# TVML - Navigate through templates

Tags: apple-tv, tvos, tvml

I´m doing something very wrong, but I´m not very sure of what.
I am trying to create an app which loads a TVML template. From there, you can navigate to a new view (also a template) with information about the selected item. Finally, in this view, you can choose to play the video.
It works until I play the view because it loads but the second screen is on top. I have to "go back" with the menu button to see the video...
Here is my code (simplified of menus and buttons):

**application.js**

```
var resourceLoader;
App.onLaunch = function(options) {
  var javascriptFiles = [
    `${options.BASEURL}/js/ResourceLoader.js`, 
    `${options.BASEURL}/js/Presenter.js`
  ];

  evaluateScripts(javascriptFiles, function(success) {
    if(success) {
        resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader(options.BASEURL);
      resourceLoader.loadResource(`${options.BASEURL}/templates/Stack.xml.js`, function(resource) {
        var doc = Presenter.makeDocument(resource);
        doc.addEventListener("select", Presenter.load.bind(Presenter));
        Presenter.pushDocument(doc);
      });


    } else {
        var errorDoc = createAlert("Evaluate Scripts Error", "Error attempting to evaluate external JavaScript files.");
        navigationDocument.presentModal(errorDoc);
    }
  });
}
```

**Presenter.js**

```
function getDocument(url) {
     var templateXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
     templateXHR.responseType = "document";
     templateXHR.addEventListener("load", function() {
            pushDoc(templateXHR.responseXML);}, false);
     templateXHR.open("GET", url, true);
     templateXHR.send();
     return templateXHR;
   }

   function pushDoc(document) {
        navigationDocument.pushDocument(document);
    }

var Presenter = {

  makeDocument: function(resource) {
    if (!Presenter.parser) {
      Presenter.parser = new DOMParser();
    }
    var doc = Presenter.parser.parseFromString(resource, "application/xml");
    return doc;
  },

  modalDialogPresenter: function(xml) {
    navigationDocument.presentModal(xml);
  },

  pushDocument: function(xml) {
    navigationDocument.pushDocument(xml);
  },

  load: function(event) {
      console.log(event);

      var self = this,
      ele = event.target,

      videoURL = ele.getAttribute("video"),
      templateURL = ele.getAttribute("template"),
      presentation = ele.getAttribute("presentation"); 

      if(videoURL) {   
            var player = new Player();
            var playlist = new Playlist();
            var mediaItem = new MediaItem("video", videoURL);

            player.playlist = playlist;
            player.playlist.push(mediaItem);
            player.present(); 
       }

      if(templateURL) {
            self.showLoadingIndicator(presentation);
            resourceLoader.loadResource(templateURL,
                function(resource) {
                    if (resource) {
                        var doc = self.makeDocument(resource);
                        doc.addEventListener("select", self.load.bind(self));
                        //doc.addEventListener("highlight", self.load.bind(self));
                        if (self[presentation] instanceof Function) {
                            self[presentation].call(self, doc, ele);
                        } else {
                            self.defaultPresenter.call(self, doc);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );             
   }   
 },


 showLoadingIndicator: function(presentation) {
        if (!this.loadingIndicator) {
            this.loadingIndicator = this.makeDocument(this.loadingTemplate);
        }

        if (!this.loadingIndicatorVisible && presentation != "modalDialogPresenter" && presentation != "menuBarItemPresenter") {
            navigationDocument.pushDocument(this.loadingIndicator);
            this.loadingIndicatorVisible = true;
        }
    },

    removeLoadingIndicator: function() {
        if (this.loadingIndicatorVisible) {
            navigationDocument.removeDocument(this.loadingIndicator);
            this.loadingIndicatorVisible = false;
        }
    },


    defaultPresenter: function(xml) {
        if(this.loadingIndicatorVisible) {
            navigationDocument.replaceDocument(xml, this.loadingIndicator);
            this.loadingIndicatorVisible = false;
        } else {
            navigationDocument.pushDocument(xml);
        }
    },

      loadingTemplate: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <document>
          <loadingTemplate>
            <activityIndicator>
              <text>Loading...</text>
            </activityIndicator>
          </loadingTemplate>
        </document>`   
}
```

I also use a ResourceLoader.js file but I think it is not important as it is the one shown in documentation.

When the app launches, I therefore load my first "template" view.
**Stack.xml.js**

```
var Template = function() { return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<document>
  <stackTemplate> 
    <collectionList>
      <carousel>
        <section>
          <lockup>
            <img src="${this.BASEURL}/images/main_carousel/main_carousel001.png" width="1740" height="500" />
            <overlay>
              <title>Title</title>
              <subtitle>1902</subtitle>
            </overlay>
          </lockup>
         </section>
      </carousel>

      <shelf>
        <header>
          <title>Last Added</title>
        </header>
        <section>
          <lockup template="${this.BASEURL}/templates/Product-001.xml.js" presentation="modalDialogPresenter">
            <img src="${this.BASEURL}/images/movies/movie001.png" width="332" height="500" />
            <title class="scrollTextOnHighlight">My Title</title>
          </lockup>
        </section>
      </shelf>

    </collectionList>
  </stackTemplate>
</document>`
}
```

When click on the image, I load my next template using the **template** parameter. This template is **Product-001.xml.js**

```
var Template = function() { return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<document>
  <productTemplate theme="light">

    <shelf>
        <header>
          <title>Last Added</title>
        </header>
        <section>
          <lockup video="http://trailers.apple.com/movies/focus_features/9/9-clip_480p.mov">
            <img src="${this.BASEURL}/resources/images/movies/movie_520_e2.lcr" width="332" height="500" />
            <title class="showAndScrollTextOnHighlight">Title 2</title>
          </lockup>

        </section>
     </shelf>  
   </productTemplate>
</document>`
}
```

This is using the **video** parameter. On the first "screen" everything works, no matter if I try to load a Template or a video. However, the same code does´t seem to work on the second screen.
Could someone help me with this?
I don´t know much about Javascript.

I have seen some posts where people say you must push the pages on the stack like this:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var newPageDocument = parser.parseFromString(NEW_PAGE_XML, 'application/xml');
navigationDocument.pushDocument(newPageDocument);
```

If this is the solution, I would be very grateful if someone could explain me where does that code need to be. Or how can I implement it correctly if I want multiple screens.
Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this happens because you are using presentation="modalDialogPresenter" to load Product-001.xml.js file.
Your video may be staying behind the modal, try to see if you can see it when you press Escape.
Then remove that part and test it again.
"modalDialogPresenter" is geared for alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Hey did you finally get the answer to this. I had a similar issue, my video was playing in the background. I could hear the audio but it was "covered" by the current template. The way I fixed this was somewhat of a hack, but i just simply dismissedModally the current view in the function that plays the video. I have a function in my presenter class that plays the video.I don't see this in your code. I think this is what your referring to. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this in the Presenter file.
It seems to work ok:

```
if(templateURL) {
        self.showLoadingIndicator(presentation);
        resourceLoader.loadResource(templateURL,
            function(resource) {
                if (resource) {
                    var doc = self.makeDocument(resource);
                    doc.addEventListener("select", self.load.bind(self));
                    //doc.addEventListener("highlight", self.load.bind(self));
                    if (self[presentation] instanceof Function) {
                      //  self[presentation].call(self, doc, ele);
                        self.defaultPresenter.call(self, doc);
                    } 
                    /* else { self.defaultPresenter.call(self, doc); }
                    */
                }
            }
        );
```

Hope it helps!